# Displaying type and value with Reason

Tags: types, ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, reason

The OCaml REPL displays the value and type of any expression. For instance, evaluating:

```
let rec map f = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::l -> f x :: map f l;;
```

Gives:

```
val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

This is unvaluable for teaching the language.

I am considering switching to Reason, but how would you obtain the same informations?

```
let rec map = (f) =>
  fun
  | [] => []
  | [x, ...l] => [f(x), ...map(f, l)];
```

[Try Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/try/) doesn't display any type, and I am not sure if there exists a REPL for Reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rtop` is a toplevel (REPL in OCaml-lingo) that ships with `reason-cli`, and that is really just a thin wrapper around `utop`. It'll print the type like this:

```
let map: (('a) => 'b, list('a)) => list('b) = <fun>;
```

In VSCode, merlin will also give you the type of let bindings in a "CodeLens" displayed above each binding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had just played with TryReason and googled "Reason REPL". https://github.com/reasonml/reason-cli should make the trick.